# Excerpt from question body missing in tag filters

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, tag-filters

The excerpt from the question body that is usually shown in question lists is suddenly missing from tag filters on stackexchange.com:

[image]

This bug happened just now, so probably the latest build broke something there.

Comment: [Probably related to this recent update](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16034598#16034598), that [just went live a moment ago](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16043167#16043167)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies for that - I missed that reuse of the view for the filtered tags page when working on the hot questions/homepage redesign.

Fixing and building out shortly.